# Computer wakes from sleep by itself when I plug another device

Tags: windows, sleep, power, desktop, mode

I recently bought a desktop PC, and I've noticed something weird happening.
Whenever the PC is in sleep mode and I plug another device somewhere in the room, the PC wakes from sleep on its own.
I have my MacBook Pro on the same desk, and today I was doing iPhone backups - just plugging the iPhone cable in the MacBook Pro USB port (via a dongle), made the PC wake up from sleep mode, even though there's nothing connecting the 2 machines. 
Even plugging a mouse or any other device (External drive, iPhone cable, MacBook Pro charging cable, etc...) produces the same effect (even things that have a very low power consumption).

I did a few tests and made sure not moving the PC mouse or keyboard accidentally - so these are not responsible for waking up the computer, it's clearly due to other separate devices.

I'm not sure what to do, and I'm not familiar at all with Windows (this is my first Windows machine) and electrical stuff in general. Has anyone already experimented the same problem, and if yes is there a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: I've done this by moving the mouse (or desk) slightly; so slightly that I could not notice it. Have you tried turning the mouse upside down?

Comment: @jpaugh Thanks for your reply! Yes, I even unplugged the peripherals from the PC usb ports entirely, but the problem persisted, that's why I thought it was caused by plugging/unplugging other devices in the same room.

Comment: That is weird! What version of Windows is it?

Comment: Yes, definitely...It's running on Windows 10 (version 1709)

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Electricity

Explanation: This problem is familiar to me. I have a PC tower in my bedroom (under the desk) that wakes from sleep when I receive static discharge from random objects on the desk. Objects not connected to the PC. In the winter when humidity is low, any static discharge produced near the vicinity of the PC tower will wake it.

In your case, it could be static, but could also be small power surges inside the wiring of your room. Try putting a rubber mat under your PC tower so the case is completely insulated, and make sure the PSU is properly grounded. Also, do not have your PC tower down on the carpet, directly touching the carpet.

Comment: Wow! I really would like to know if this is the answer. My PC is probably vulnerable right now...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and explanations! I'll definitely try that, and I'll see if it solves the problem.